# How to delete rows from a excel using OLEDB

Tags: .net

How to delete rows from a excel using OLEDB?
I tried with Delete from [sheet1$] but it's not working.

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I recently ran into the same problem:
It is not to delete using OleDb with Excel

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934

> Although the Jet OLE DB Provider
>   allows you to insert and update
>   records in an Excel workbook, it does
>   not allow DELETE operations. If you
>   try to perform a DELETE operation on
>   one or more records, you receive the
>   following error message...